# IoC/MEF container

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, mef, ioc-container

In my interface package i have this following piece of code that runs when the user wants to change some info about a artist:

```
IArtist artistToChange = ContainerHelper.Container.GetExportedValue<IArtist>();
artistToChange.Load(new Guid("provided guid"));
artistToChange.SomeProperty = newValue;
artistToChange.Update();
```

Being Artist a entity in my domain it is composed among other stuff by a `IUser CreatedBy` & `IUser LastAlteredBy` properties that must be loaded (think of Many-To-One relationship). Each Entity also has its own repository. IArtist has a IArtistRepository the same way IUser has `IUserRepository`.

My problem is the following: *How can I get a instance of a concrete implementation of `IUser` inside of `IArtist.Load()` while maintaining IoC (without the concrete implementation of `IArtist` not knowing about the concrete implementation of `IUser`)?*

(To make things easy let's call of `CArtist` the concrete implementation of `IArtist`, and `CUser` the implementation of `IUser`.)

With that in mind i though about passing the container to the **Entities** so they could also request parts, but i dont know if that is a good idea or even a anti-pattern, mainly because im using constructor injection and my constructor for 'CArtist' looks like this:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public CArtist(IArtistRepository repository)
{
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

but i cant get the container to inject itself with something like

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public CArtist(IArtistRepository repository, CompositionContainer container)
{
    this.container = container    
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

So this is basically it... i'm quite lost here... this turned out to be a cry for help/guidance more than a question on itself...

**PS: If any other information is necessary pls ask for it!**

Comment: How do you intend to use the container in the CArtist class? Will the container give you more flexibility than properties decorated with ImportAttribute?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you properly export a concrete `IArtist` class, you can do the following in your code, and then as long as the dll's are available, when you compose the `CArtist` class, the `IArtist` type would get injected into the class.  You may be able to even get away with a private variable `private IArtist _someArtist;` (marked with the import attribute)

```
public class CArtist : IArtist
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public CArtist(IArtistRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void Load(Guid guid)
    {
        this.SomeArtist.DoSomething(guid);
        ...
    }

    [Import(typeof(IArtist))]
    private IArtist SomeArtist { get; set; }
}
```

Another approach, would be to, again use a property or var in the class, and import it in the constructor

```
private IArtist _artist;

[ImportingConstructor]
public CArtist(IArtistRepository repository, IArtist artist)
{
    this.repository = repository;
    this._artist = artist;
}
```

Aside from those possible approaches, imho passing the container wouldn't be too big of a problem, it would work and you still maintain the separation, I've seen that done in a few places, but I'm no expert in IoC to know definitively whether it's a good or bad practice.

Comment: interesting... so far i placed the container in the Library (project the only has the interfaces and enumerators) because all projects reference it... I created a helper class that would return the container as a singleton... i think this is a good approach... what do you think?

Comment: @Leonardo it would work, like the saying goes, *there is more than one way to skin a cat* (note to everyone, no cat was actually harmed in this idiomatic expression).  Though I personally wouldn't take this approach, imho the client(s) should take care of composing whatever is needed, and not the shared lib where the interfaces and enums are  :)